# Assigning class name to a variable

Tags: ruby

I saw something like this in someone's code:

```
class Test01
  def initialize
    puts "some text"
  end
end

x = Test01 #this part confuses me
y = Test02 #I added this to see what will happen
a = x.new #works like expected

p a.class #Test01
p x.class #Class
p y.class #Error: uninitialized constant
```

- What is x? One time it's class Class, other time it is constant
- Is this bad practice? If it is, what is proper way to do it?

Comment: `y = Test02` should already raise `NameError: uninitialized constant Test02`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `Test01` constant to `x`, and `Test01` constant value is class, so your `x` contains `Test01` class.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby treats everything like an object.  This includes the class definition as well as numbers, your custom classes, etc.  This consistency helps get your head around Ruby a bit quicker.  However, it does make some things possible that would be impossible in other languages.

When you see

```
x = Test01
```

you are basically making `x` hold the constant value of `Test01`.  You can pass it to methods, do reflection, or even add new methods to `x` just as you can with `Test01`.  That's why

```
a = x.new
b = Test01.new
```

are essentially the same command.  In both cases you get an instance of the `Test01` class as a new object.  `x` is still assigned to the `Test01` class itself.  `a` is an *instance* of `Test01` and `x` *is* `Test01`.

```
Test01.class # returns 'Class'
x.class      # returns 'Class'
a.class      # returns 'Test01' because it is an instance of 'Test01'
```

Comment: An alias refers to [something else](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias) in Ruby. `x = Test01` assigns the constant `Test01` to `x` (i.e. the constant's value).

Comment: My apologies.  I wasn't trying to confuse terminology, merely say that `x` and `Test01` can be treated as if they were the same thing.  It's logically an alias, just not in the sense defined by the `alias` keyword in Ruby.  I edited my answer to reflect your comment.